# In brownie tests how to use interfaces defined in packages

Tags: testing, openzeppelin, brownie

In brownie tests how to use third party interfaces defined in brownie packages?
For example how do I use
`@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol`

from OpenZeppelin upgradeable package in brownie tests?

Comment: Could you put an example of what you expect this to look like? I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Does this repo help you at all? https://github.com/brownie-mix/upgrades-mix